# How to edit OS version in the emulator without losing data

Tags: android

I have a scenario to test when the app upgrades from android 11 to 12. So, I have installed the app in the emulator with android 11. After that I edited the emulator OS to android 12. When I edit the emulator and open it again, it has no apps installed in it. So, can someone suggest a way to edit the emulator without losing my app.